# Migrating to spring.config.activate.on-profile in Spring Boot 3

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am in the process of migrating an old Spring Boot application from 2.3.5.RELEASE to version 3.1.2 and attempting to update a module that uses configuration file format to align with the new profile activation mechanism introduced in Spring Boot 2.4. Previously, I was using spring.profiles to activate different configurations based on the active profile. However, in the new version, it seems that spring.config.activate.on-profile is the recommended approach.

Here is an excerpt from my original configuration file (src/test/resources/example/auto-loaded/config-file.yaml):

```
auto-loaded:
  yaml-config-file:
    yaml-config-file-property: default value

---
spring:
  profiles: some-env

auto-loaded:
  yaml-config-file:
    yaml-config-file-property: value for some-env

---
spring:
  profiles: some-other-env

auto-loaded:
  yaml-config-file:
    yaml-config-file-property: value for some-other-env
    some-other-env-property: expected not to be loaded
```

I attempted to migrate this to the new format as follows:

```
auto-loaded:
  yaml-config-file:
    yaml-config-file-property: default value

---
spring:
  config:
    activate:
      on-profile: some-env

auto-loaded:
  yaml-config-file:
    yaml-config-file-property: value for some-env

---
spring:
  config:
    activate:
      on-profile: some-other-env

auto-loaded:
  yaml-config-file:
    yaml-config-file-property: value for some-other-env
    some-other-env-property: expected not to be loaded
```

After updating the configuration file, I am not seeing the expected behavior when activating the profiles some-env and some-other-env. The properties don't seem to be loaded or overridden as they were before the migration.

Here are my questions:

Is my updated configuration file format correct according to the new profile activation mechanism in Spring Boot 3?
Are there additional steps needed to ensure that the profile-specific configurations are loaded and applied correctly?
more details can be found here https://github.com/negadras/config-properties (test class DefaultConfigLoaderTest and DefaultConfigLoaderWithProfileTest)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case you should use

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: some-env
```

More details about it you can find in [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/3.0.0-M4/reference/htmlsingle/#howto.properties-and-configuration.set-active-spring-profiles)

About

```
spring:
  config:
    activate:
      on-profile: some-env
```

Also all that you need is described in [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/3.0.0-M4/reference/htmlsingle/#howto.properties-and-configuration.change-configuration-depending-on-the-environment) (can be used to mark a configuration file segment profile-specific.)

Answer (score 0):

In your application’s bootstrap.yml

```
spring:
  profiles: 
    active: myprofile
```

The above can be used in non-profile specific files.

In your central configuration corresponding yml. The code block below is used to activate or override a specific profile

```
spring: 
  config: 
    activate: 
      on-profile: myprofile
```

That should fix the issue.

https://spring.io/blog/2020/08/14/config-file-processing-in-spring-boot-2-4/